# How to pass parameters to parent class with type() in python?

Tags: python, class, inheritance, types, parameters

```
class Parent(object):

    def __init__(self, first):
        self.first = first

class Child1(Parent):

    def __init__(self):
        Parent.__init__(self, 'A')
```

- I have this Parent class and i want to make 12 similar classes that inherit Parent class, all with the same signature and NO parameters. How do i define Child1, using `type()`?
  So far I have 
  `Child1 = type('Child1', (Rank,), dict())` but how can i pass `first` to `Parent` class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you use the attributes dictionary. i think something like this should do the trick.

```
def genericInit(self):
    Parent.__init__(self, 'A')

type('Child1', (Rank,), {'__init__': genericInit})
```

updated per comments:
you could use `functools.partial`

```
attrDict = {'init': functools.partial(Parent.__init__, first='A')}
```

but this is bad code. you generally don't want to be calling **init** from anywhere other than **init** because it's really confusing to anyone using your class.

Comment: Child1 = type('Child1', (Parent,), {'__init__' : Parent.__init__('A')}) i want to do something like that, but this is not working ?

Comment: that's failing because you need to pass an instance of `Parent` to `Parent`'s __init__ method. you're trying to call that at type instantiation, but you need to call it when you instantiate the class. why does the above not work?

Comment: I have to make more than 10 child classes and i don't want to make genericInt for each aand every one of them.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve? http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem